# Matlab efficiently take diagonal values of a matrix product

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-multiplication, diagonal

I have two matrices, a is 2000 by 20000, b is also 2000 by 20000. I want to get the diagonal elements of `a'*b`. I used `diag(a'*b)` but it is very slow (about 20 seconds), since calculating non-diagonal elements takes time. I am wondering if there are faster ways to do this.

I noticed people do something like `sum((T*H).*T',2)`, here is the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/288040). But it is required that T is a square matrix. How about non-square matrix in my case?

Thanks

Comment: complete your matrices with zeros to square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal of `a'*b` is just

```
result = sum(a'.*b.',2);
```

Example (with non-square matrices):

```
>> a = rand(4,5);
>> b = rand(4,5);
>> result = sum(a'.*b.',2)
result =
    1.6102
    0.2805
    1.5354
    0.3966
    1.1896

>> diag(a'*b)
ans =
    1.6102
    0.2805
    1.5354
    0.3966
    1.1896
```